# R In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :

Tags: r, encoding

I have two functions they are :

```
A:
a=3;
b=5;
print(a+b)
source("C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Deneme1/B")
B(a,b)
```

and B:

```
B <- function(a,b) 
{
  print(a*b)
}
```

When i try to run i get this error:

Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : bağlantı açılamadı
Ek olarak: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
dosya 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Deneme1/B' açılamadı: No such file or directory

Can you please help me? Thank you...

Comment: have you tried saving B with UTF-8 encoding? (using R studio you have the option on the "file" button to "save with encoding")

Comment: also not sure if you need to inform the file ending (like "B.r") when sourcing as it is possible to have multiple files of name "B" but with different ending (file types) in the same folder

Comment: i have just tried saving B with UTF-8 encoding. Not working.

Comment: Second suggestion worked :-) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The solution is DPH second comment: "also not sure if you need to inform the file ending (like "B.r") when sourcing as it is possible to have multiple files of name "B" but with different ending (file types) in the same folder . "